# Thymeleaf, send object to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I use spring mvc and thymeleaf and I received model object, so I have something like that :

```
<li th:each="game : ${availableGames}">
      <a class="gameLink" href="#" th:text="${game.getId()}" th:object="${game}"/>
</li>
```

How to use this object in ajax and send it to controller ? 
I tried this

```
  var ob = $(this).object()
  data : JSON.stringify(ob.JSON()),
  contentType: 'application/json',
```

but it isn't working

Answer (score 3):

Like in [tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart) you can pass object to JS variable this way:

`var games = /*[[${availableGames}]]*/ null;`

If you want to send selected game to controller you can find selected id in games array and send it using Ajax.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok, but then I have to iterate twice the same list. Isn't it possible to send game object directly to ajax after user click this option ?

Comment: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart working link